# handling soap envelope in objective C

Tags: iphone, soap, nsstring, sudzc

I'm trying to acces a SOAP web service in iOS with sudzc.com. It seems i get soap envelope in return. But i'm unsure of how to handle the result. Can i somehow put the result in a NSDictionary or how do i proceed?

```
    - (void)run {
// Create the service
SDZDevices2Api* service = [SDZDevices2Api service];
service.logging = YES;
    // Returns NSString*. (added searchstring and max count values)
[service LocationFindSimple:self action:@selector(LocationFindSimpleHandler:) SearchString: @"Vejle" Max: 1 BankId: [NSMutableArray array] BankName: [NSMutableArray array] Id: [NSMutableArray array] Name: [NSMutableArray array] Icon: [NSMutableArray array] Zip: [NSMutableArray array] Attributes: [NSMutableArray array]];
   }

// Handle the response from LocationFindSimple.

- (void) LocationFindSimpleHandler: (id) value {

// Handle errors
if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
}

// Handle faults
if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
}

// Do something with the NSString* result
  NSString* result = (NSString*) value;
    NSLog(@"LocationFindSimple returned the value: %@", result);
}
```

This is the log message:

http://pastebin.com/JycGq4Du

Comment: Just curious, why use SOAP? In my opinion, SOAP is way too heavy for mobile environment. Have you looked at the REST method of doing things? (Unless your business constraints hold you down to SOAP)

Comment: Yeah it is the business constraints, everything here is within .Net framework (SOAP is pretty easy to use when writing in VB as I understand). I was hoping that this could work, if not I guess I have to look into other formats. Haven't really looked at REST yet. Is it considered best practice, or is JSON also a possibility?

Comment: Almost all mobile environment (pretty much every web service centric application) use REST for its light payload. REST can support both XML and JSON, and JSON is considered best practice for its lightweight and object notation (something that XML can accomplish, but with pain). I recently made a `WCF REST Service Application` for work whose environment a bit dated and it worked (I had to push my boss on adopting it). It works with .NET 4.0, but I think it works with 3.5 as well. If time is not a major constraint, I would suggest switching (useful when payload gets larger)

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The boss is not dismissive of using JSON, so will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone else with this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829085/handling-sudzcs-response-result-nsmutablearray/9935832#9935832)

```
if( [value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]] ) 
{

NSLog(@"%@", [value description]);
return;
}

// Verify we're a dictionary
if( ![value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {

NSLog(@"ERROR: Response not a dictionary");
return;
}

NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*)value;
NSDictionary* resp = [dict objectForKey:@"E_AN"];
if( ( resp == nil ) || ![resp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {

NSLog(@"ERROR: E_AN not a dictionary");
return;
}
dict = [resp objectForKey:@"item"];
if( ( dict == nil ) || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {

NSLog(@"ERROR: item not a dictionary");
return;
}
resp = [dict objectForKey:@"MANDT"];
if( ( resp == nil ) || ![resp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {

NSLog(@"ERROR: MANDT not a dictionary");
return;
}
```